# my email validation in java script is not working properly

Tags: javascript

my code is below both are in diffrent pages

```
<tr>
  <td width="100">email:</td><td width="100"><input type="email" name="mailid" id="mail" onKeyUp="validateemail()" required></td><td><label id="vem"></label></td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
function validateemail() {
    var chmail=document.getElementById("mail");
    if(chmail.match(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/))
    {
        producePrompt("valid email","vem","green"); 
        return false;

    }

    producePrompt("email invalid","vem","red"); 
        return true;


}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent e-mail regexes...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the question against which it is marked as duplicate. That question blindly asks how to do something. The OP is asking what is wrong with his code. I'm not at all saying this is a good question, but closing questions with incorrect reason is a bad idea - atleast it should be closed with a proper reason... Hence voting to re-open.

Answer (score 0):

```
var chmail=document.getElementById("mail"); //returns the input element.
```

replace it with

```
var chmail=document.getElementById("mail").value; // returns the value
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8JfWh/)

*side note: hopefully producePrompt() is defined somewhere in your code..*